# Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/widget/CompoundButton Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, radio-button, nosuchmethoderror

I get this error:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;.getButtonDrawable()Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;

When I am using a radio button ButtonDrawable like this:

```
    if(myRadioButton.ButtonDrawable == null)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```

I tested the app on android API  = 23 (Marshmallow) and it works fine. I get this error for android API < 23 (older than Marshmallow)

I am using Xamarin.Android.Support.Design version 25.3.1

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elvis is correct, it was my mistake.
In case someone has same problem, this how I solved the problem without using get button drawable.

This code for Xamarin.android but you can convert it to Java.

```
//Remove radio button circle    
 radioButton.SetButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());

//Set tag = true to know the button drawable is null
radioButton.Tag = true;
```

Later in code:

```
if(radioButton.tag.Equals(true))
{
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tested the app on android API = 23 (Marshmallow) and it works fine. I get this error for android API < 23 (older than Marshmallow)

It is expected behavior. If you refer to 
[ButtonDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#getButtonDrawable()). This api was added in API Level 23.